# Matrix of Linear Transformation

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, vector-space

Find a matrix for the Linear Transformation T: R2 → R3, defined by
T (x, y) = (13x - 9y, -x - 2y, -11x - 6y) with respect to the basis
B = {(2, 3), (-3, -4)} and C = {(-1, 2, 2), (-4, 1, 3), (1, -1, -1)} for R2 & R3
respectively.

Here, the process should be to find the transformation for the vectors of B and express those as a linear combination of C and those vectors will form the matrix for linear transformation. Is my approach correct or do I need to change something?

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how to do in python with sympy module

```py
import sympy
# Assuming that B(x, y) = (2,3)*x + (-3, -4)*y it can be expressed as a left multiplication by
B = sympy.Matrix(
    [[2, -3],
     [3, -4]])

# Then you apply T as a left multiplication by
T = sympy.Matrix(
    [[13, -9],
     [-1, -2],
     [-11, -6]])

#And finally to get the representation on the basis C you multiply of the result
# by the inverse of C

C = sympy.Matrix(
    [[-1, -4, 1],
     [2, 1, -1],
     [2, 3, -1]])

combined = C.inv() * T * B
```

The combined transformation matrix yelds

```
[[-57, 77], 
 [-16, 23], 
 [-122, 166]])
```

Comment: But how will we do it mathematically...I want to know the general method to solve the question. But thank you for this.

Comment: `C.inv() * T * B` is general enough, you can solve any problem of this class. I just applied to the problem you shown for concreteness.